# variable not being defined correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
   console.log('startX:'+startX,'startY:'+startY)
var pixelStack=[[startX, startY]];                                                  //create pixel stack with starting pixel on top
console.log('pxStack:'+pixelStack)
var test=[[startX, startY]];
console.log('test:'+test)
pixelStack=test
console.log(pixelStack,test)
```

When I run this code (it's contained inside a function) test is defined correctly, but pixelStack is defined as an empty array ([]), when i run pixelStack=test they both become an empty array. Here is my console output:

> startX:250 startY:250
>   pxStack:250,250
>   test:250,250
>   [] []

(I'm in Google Chrome)

Comment: Works for me. Is this simplified code and maybe missing something?

Comment: This is a 'clip' from a larger function, but this code is run at the beginning before any variables can be manipulated

Comment: Works just fine for me too.. You probably have other code that manipulates those variables.

Comment: This is run at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I just ran it in firefox and it worked fine, could this be a chrome bug?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. It must be something else in your code. Can you post more of it?

Comment: Is this code inside `with(...) { ... }` in your original?

Answer (score 0):

It Works For Me™

http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/KLcPe/

Comment: I ran that in Chrome and it worked. *(I love the way the output is interactive when you pass a raw object.)*

Comment: Works for me too, Chromium 10.0.648.151 (Arch Linux).